# Does Detox support Physical Devices when run from CI environment?

Tags: continuous-integration, detox

It's not totally clear to me if i can test Physical Devices (Android) with Detox when running on a CI (Jenkins or CircleCI) Environment.

I Expect to test Real Devices (only Android) as well as Emulators on Detox when Run on a CI environment